# how to block plugin.64 from asking for access to keychain

Tags: macos, keychain

how do I stop this message from popping up on my MacBook 12":

com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64 wants to use your confidential information stored in "v4.services.acrobat.com" in your keychain

it asks me to enter Password, then click DENY or ALLOW. but no option for ALWAYS DENY.

Comment: If you don’t get a good answer, please edit your post to say what web browser specifically you want this fixed in first. It could simply be a browser setting